Is ciphertext byte $i$ and byte $i+1$ related in a stream cipher like Zip Crypto?
In zip crypto the equations for key update is:
$key2_i = \frac{key2_{i-1}}{256}\, \oplus crctab[x_i]$
$key1_ = (key1_{i-1}+LSB(key0_i))*const +1$
$key0_i = \frac {key0_{i-1}}{256}\, \oplus crctab[y_i]$
$key3_i = LSB((z_i*(z_i\oplus1))>>8)$
where $z_i$ is $key2_i |3\, mod \,65536 $
Then encryption and decryption uses:
$k3_i = p_i \oplus c_i$
Since $key2_i$ is derived from $key2_{i-1}$ and it derives $key3_i$ then theoretically the $c_i$ and $c_{i-1}$ are related somehow.
